# How to turn this list into a data frame? I would like to know how to do this in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, helper

I have a list in python which is showing like this just below. I would like to turn it into a data frame. I tried it: **pd.DataFrame(myList)**, however the **'origins' column** stores a **list**, however I would like to store the **origin and quantityLeads keys** in that same dataframe

```
myList = [
   {
      "id":3105052,
      "title":"Ebook Relat�rios Gerenciais",
      "offering":"Institucional",
      "created_date":"2022-06-28"
      "inserted_date":"2022-06-28",
      "channel":"Social",
      "start_date":"2022-06-28",
      "end_date":"2022-06-28",
      "origins":[
         {
            "origin":"LinkedIn",
            "quantityLeads":"1"
         },
         {
            "origin":"Facebook",
            "quantityLeads":"1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3105052,
      "title":"Ebook Relat�rios Gerenciais",
      "offering":"Institucional",
      "inserted_date":"2022-06-28",
      "created_date":"2022-06-28",
      "channel":"Direct",
      "start_date":"2022-06-28",
      "end_date":"2022-06-28",
      "origins":[
         {
            "origin":"Desconhecida",
            "quantityLeads":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2918513,
      "title":"Ebook Direct To Consumer",
      "offering":"Supply Chain",
      "created_date":"2022-06-28",
      "inserted_date":"2022-06-28",
      "channel":"Social",
      "start_date":"2022-06-28",
      "end_date":"2022-06-28",
      "origins":[
         {
            "origin":"LinkedIn",
            "quantityLeads":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: does the origins list always have one item? If no, then how would you handle multiple elements?

Comment: is that even valid json ?

Comment: @Sergio Peñafiel
The list called origins can have more than one element, I was thinking of repeating the same lines that have the same Channel. And then add columns for each origin key and quantityLeads

Comment: Just make the Origins dataset a dict rather than a list and store that data as a dict inside each of your list elements.

Answer (score 1):

In the pursuit of simplicity you could just flatten the dictionary structures with something like:

```
for row in myList:
   row["origin"] = row["origins"][0]["origin"]
   row["quantityLeads"] = row["origins"][0]["quantityLeads"]
   del row["origins"]

df = pd.DataFrame(myList)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        id                        title       offering created_date inserted_date channel  start_date    end_date        origin quantityLeads
0  3105052  Ebook Relat�rios Gerenciais  Institucional   2022-06-28    2022-06-28  Social  2022-06-28  2022-06-28      LinkedIn             1
1  3105052  Ebook Relat�rios Gerenciais  Institucional   2022-06-28    2022-06-28  Direct  2022-06-28  2022-06-28  Desconhecida             2
2  2918513     Ebook Direct To Consumer   Supply Chain    2022-06-28    2022-06-28  Social  2022-06-28  2022-06-28      LinkedIn             1
```

Just as a side note, for the myList sample above there is a missing comma after the first entry's created_date that's causing an error.

EDIT: If there are a variable number of items in the origins list, but each item has the same keys then we could iterate over those as well.

```
for row in myList:
   origins_list = row["origins"]
   counter = 0
   for item in origins_list:
      row["origin_" + str(counter)] = item["origin"]
      row["quantityLeads_" + str(counter)] = item["quantityLeads"]
      counter += 1

   del row["origins"]

df = pd.DataFrame(myList)
print(df)
```

Comment: However the "origins" key can have more than one element. It would be interesting to add new lines with these elements, but with the other keys the same

Comment: Okay sure, if there is a variable number of items in the "origins" list we can loop over those too . We can add more columns as needed - edited above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one element in "origins" you may first explode, create "origin", "quantityLeads" and then decide what to do with rest of the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myList)
df = df.explode('origins')
df[['origin', 'quantityLeads']] = pd.DataFrame(df['origins'].tolist())
df.drop('origins', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

print(df):

```
        id                        title       offering created_date  \
0  3105052  Ebook Relat�rios Gerenciais  Institucional   2022-06-28   
1  3105052  Ebook Relat�rios Gerenciais  Institucional   2022-06-28   
2  2918513     Ebook Direct To Consumer   Supply Chain   2022-06-28   

  inserted_date channel  start_date    end_date        origin quantityLeads  
0    2022-06-28  Social  2022-06-28  2022-06-28      LinkedIn             1  
1    2022-06-28  Direct  2022-06-28  2022-06-28  Desconhecida             2  
2    2022-06-28  Social  2022-06-28  2022-06-28      LinkedIn             1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myList)
df = df.explode('origins')
df['origin'] = df.origins.str.get('origin')
df['quantityLeads'] = df.origins.str.get('quantityLeads')
df.drop('origins', axis=1, inplace=True)
```